# How make custom helper for Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want create a helper that works like **`Ajax.ActionLink`**. I create a helper to do this with some changes :

```
@helper AjaxLink(string innerhtml, string href, string targetId)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerhtml))
    {
        if (href.Trim() == "#")
        {
            <a href="@(href)">
                @MvcHtmlString.Create(innerhtml)
            </a>
        }
        else
        {
            <a href="@(href)" data-ajax-update="#@(targetId)" data-ajax-mode="replace">
                @MvcHtmlString.Create(innerhtml)
            </a>
        }

    }
}
```

My helper create a link like :

```
<a href="ItemRegister?testTypeId=1" data-ajax-update="#pageId" data-ajax-mode="replace">
     <i class="fa fa-sign-out"><span style="right: -47px;" class="icon-bg bg-orange"></span></i><span>Register </span>
</a>
```

But it doesn't work! It refresh page instead of fill target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `data-ajax` attribute into your `<a>` tags:

```
<a href="@(href)" data-ajax-update="#@(targetId)" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax="true">
       @MvcHtmlString.Create(innerhtml)
</a>
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot link to `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` . You right! thx